# Convert HTML Tags Using C#

Tags: c#, html

I have a situation where I need to convert a nested HTML list like this:

```
<ol>
<li>Item 1
    <ol>
        <li> Item 1.1
            <ol>
                <li>Item 1.1.1</li>
                <li>Item 1.1.2</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>
<li>Item 2
    <ol>
        <li> Item 2.1
            <ol>
                <li>Item 2.1.1</li>
                <li>Item 2.1.2</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>
```

Into separate indented tables (where each ol is a table, indented properly to look like the nested table). What would be the best way to do this? I've looked that the HtmlAgility pack, but I couldn't figure out how to replace tags once I found them (I was able to find all the appropriate tags, but couldn't do anything with them)...

Basically, I need the output table(s) to look something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        &bull;
    </td>
    <td>
        Item 1
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<table style="margin-left: 5px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            &bull;
        </td>
        <td>
            Item 1.1
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="margin-left: 10px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            &bull;
        </td>
        <td>
            Item 1.1.1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &bull;
        </td>
        <td>
            Item 1.1.2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &bull;
        </td>
        <td>
            Item 2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="margin-left: 5px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            &bull;
        </td>
        <td>
            Item 2.1
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="margin-left: 10px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            &bull;
        </td>
        <td>
            Item 2.1.1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &bull;
        </td>
        <td>
            Item 2.1.2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Would a regular expression replacing `<ol>` with `<table>` and `<li>` with `<tr><td>` not work?

Answer (score 3):

Just break down what you're trying to do into simpler steps.

1) Replace all `<ol>` with `<table><tr>`
2) Replace all `<li>` with `<td>`
3) Replace all `</li>` with `</td>`
4) Replace all `</ol>` with `</tr></table>`

...Or similar. Its basically a straight up translation if I'm understanding your issue correctly.

Comment: This is what I tried originally, but the problem is, the resulting tables can't be nested...